# multipart request's response decode is not happening

Tags: android, api, flutter, http-post

in dart i uploaded a list of named images in Map in multipart request. while getting response, JSON is broken exception in coming. Actually the response splits itself into two line and showing can't decode......

```
 [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unterminated string (at character 1054)
E/flutter (24484): ...\/1**.***.*.***\/Q2\/console\/img\/show_image?dir=animak_image\/BK  <----


[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)
E/flutter (24484): ----> 00004\/xHohpYaL9ZMKACJd.jpg&w=&h=100","medium":"http:\/\/1**.***.*.***\/Q2\..
```

in above, ......dir=animak_image/**BK**00004/xHohpYaL9ZMKACJd.jpg....this line breaks in two line

Comment: How JOSN can split itself, its the response from the server

Comment: yeah you're right. in my case streamed response comes in future ....mistake i did is started decoding before response received completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah it's simple ....stream is future value off-course. so i did await instead stream..... like...

```
 await request.send().then((value) async {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        fetchedResponse = response;
      }
    });
```